# Populate a Google slide automatically via Google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-slides

Is there a way in Google Slides to populate a slide with content that is referenced from a range in a Google spreadsheet?

Answer (score -1):

Update!

You can now insert a live chart into your Google Slide.
If you want to add a range, I suggest making a table chart and inserting your data like this.

[Here's a link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h2_oiGv3ZdQ) to the Google Dev channel video regarding this. There's an easier to use "Insert-->chart" option in Slides.

Comment: Add essential contents of the link into answer. It will helpful for the readers.

Comment: Neither of the options mentioned in this answer are well explained.  This answer could be updated an improved.